# Acceder directamente al miembro sobreescrito?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas! Tengo 3 clases, una es `TokenBase`, que es usada como padre de las demas clases:

```
abstract class TokenBase
{
    public TokenTypes Type { get; set; }
    public virtual object Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Type: {Type}\t\t Value: {Value}";
    }
}
```

Clases derivadas:

```
class StringToken : TokenBase
{
    private string _Value;
    public new string Value 
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value;}
    }
    public StringToken(string v) { Type = TokenTypes.String; Value = v; }
}

class SymbolToken : TokenBase
{
    private string _Value;
    public new Symbols Value 
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value;}
    }
    public SymbolToken(Symbols v) { Type = TokenTypes.Symbol; Value = v; }
}
```

El problema reside cuando quiero llamar a `ToString()` o `Value` en una de las clases derivadas dentro de la lista:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<TokenBase> Tokens = new List<TokenBase>();
    Tokens.Add(new StringToken("Hola Mundo"));
    foreach (TokenBase T in Tokens)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(T.ToString()); 
        // Obtengo la siguiente salida: "Type: String         Value: "
        Console.WriteLine(T.Value.ToString()); // Obtengo: ""
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// Salida esperada: "Type: String         Value: Hola Mundo"
```

Como puedo acceder directamente a la propiedad `Value` de uno de los tipos derivados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pero no necesitas realizar lo que planteas, al definir la propiedad como virtual esta tiene una implementacion para las clases hijas que podrias sobreescribir, pero en este caso no es necesario

si defines

```
abstract class TokenBase
{
    public TokenBase(TokenTypes type, string v)
    {
        Type = type; 
        Value = v; 
    }

    public TokenTypes Type { get; set; }
    public virtual object Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Type: {Type}\t\t Value: {Value}";
    }
}



class StringToken : TokenBase
{
    public StringToken(string v) 
        : base(TokenTypes.String, v) 
    { 

    }
}

class SymbolToken : TokenBase
{
    public SymbolToken(string v) 
        : base(TokenTypes.Symbol, v) 
    { 

    }
}
```

puedes desde las clases hijas asignar las propiedades de la base

Ademas si defiens una propiedad como virtual se supone que uses el [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)

Si el comportamiento debes cambiar entonces harias lo siguiente

```
abstract class TokenBase
{
    public TokenBase(TokenTypes type)
    {
        Type = type; 
    }

    public TokenTypes Type { get; set; }
    public virtual object Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Type: {Type}\t\t Value: {Value}";
    }
}



class StringToken : TokenBase
{
    public StringToken(string v) 
        : base(TokenTypes.String) 
    { 
        this.Value = v;
    }

    public override object Value 
    { 
        get{}; 
        set{ //aqui redefines la implementacion}; 
    }
}

class SymbolToken : TokenBase
{
    public SymbolToken(string v) 
        : base(TokenTypes.Symbol) 
    { 
        this.Value = v;
    }

    public override object Value 
    { 
        get{}; 
        set{ //aqui redefines la implementacion}; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Pero al usar `: base (TokenTypes.Symbol, v)` estaria asignandole un valor al object abajo, no? El caso es que hay ciertas reglas para aceptar el valor de las propiedades, por eso hice `hiding` a la propiedad virtual, funciona de igual manera?

Comment: Si por objeto abajo te refieres a la clase hija, entonces si, recuerda que las propeidades y metodos se heredan. Si hay ciertas reglas entonces deberias realizar un override de la propiedad y en el set definir esas reglas

Comment: -- Retiro, ya ví el editado. Es en base lo que necesito, veré como funciona.

Comment: Si pero por herencia seria la misma, esto es valido para una asignacion simple, ahora si hay logica aplicaria el segundo ejemplo donde reflejo como puedes sobreescribir la propiedad con logica, pera eso usas el override

Answer (score 0):

Si cambias tu clase `StringToken` por la siguiente, debería funcionar tu ejemplo:

```
class StringToken : TokenBase
{  
    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Value;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public StringToken(string v) { Type = TokenTypes.String; Value = v; }
}
```

O si quieres conservar tu propiedad `Value` de tipo `String`, puedes hacer esto otro:

```
class StringToken : TokenBase
{
    public new string Value
    {
        get { return base.Value.ToString(); }
        set { base.Value = value; }
    }

    public StringToken(string v) { Type = TokenTypes.String; Value = v; }
}
```